# Turn ON / OFF a Custom Page / Feature based on Tenant in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I want to create a setting feature where I can turn on / off a specific customized feature or page based on the tenant. For instance, I have 4 companies, on which company 2 and 3 needed a set of feature which 4 and 5 doesn't or vice versa.

I've tried implementing [Modular Graph Extensions](https://www.acumatica.com/blog/using-modular-graph-extensions-to-avoid-mega-graphs/?utm_campaign=FY20-Newsletters-Developer&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=89176512&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-8ICJZl6QqPmhMDLGbFFW6z7YgeIq7mJkkmKltg3PfDil7FsPXeJjL5-QrLPaoG3_OuT2CK10cw-II7AYXnpxp2U6a-tw&utm_content=89176512&utm_source=hs_email&fbclid=IwAR2lvs2T1giNiklhQNh6sY6uEx0s_f5wAUV_ruQPzqo_0BpWSbG2_L1Grio) and [Conditionally Activate Extensions](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/dynamically-activate-extensions.html), unfortunately it only applies to Extension Graphs or DACs. It can't be used on the main graph.

I'm thinking of just putting a conditional statement on ***RowSelected*** event but it cannot really hide the page or the feature.

Any suggestions or advice will help. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use Features.xml and disable based on Tenant? If you use Features.xml, can't you go to the Enable/Disable features of each tenant and then set it accordingly per Tenant?

Comment: @JosephCaruana yes you're right, but we've experienced problem during the licensing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a setup screen with a checkbox that will control whether you have the feature enabled.  In the screen create a PXSetup View and in the constructor check the flag for activation.  If it's not active throw a PXSetupNotEnteredException.  This will blank the page and give the user a message of your choosing.

```
    public PXSetup<CustomSettings> CustomerSettings;
    public GraphName()
    {
        CustomSettingssettings = CustomerSettings.Current;
        if (!(settings.IsthisActive?? false))
        {
            throw new PXSetupNotEnteredException("This is not enabled, typeof(CustomSettings), "Graphname");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have a question regarding this solution, I applied it on the project and it works just fine when I try to disable then enable the setup. but if i tried to disable it again, the setup won't work. tried debugging it and it only pass to the constructor twice (from disable to enable) then trying to disable it again, it won't pass to the constructor. any idea how to modify it?

Comment: So there are two screens involved right?  There's the setup screen and the screen you're trying to enable/disable.  I don't think I was clear on that.

Comment: Hey Patrick, Solved the issue. Thanks for the solution. :) My issue was caused by an overridden Persist Method. So I just removed it and it works perfectly fine now. Thank you so much!